# cut next placeholder with git pretty format e.g. to cut a date string

Tags: git, git-format

According to the [pretty format documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) you can pad a placeholder. For my example I will use the apache [commons-io git repository](https://github.com/apache/commons-io). The pad format can also take the parameter `trunc`. E.g.

```
git log --format="%<(25)%cn %<(25,trunc)%s"
```

will output something like this

```
Kristian Rosenvold        [maven-release-plugin] ..
Kristian Rosenvold        [maven-release-plugin] ..
Kristian Rosenvold        Moved to changes
Kristian Rosenvold        Updated release notes
Kristian Rosenvold        Added Shift_JIS to list..
```

The `trunc` parameter cuts the next placeholder and replaces the cut string with `..`.

Is it possible to just cut the next placeholder without adding `..`?

Cutting a placeholder is useful when e.g. I only want to output the day and not the complete dateformat. I want to write something like

```
git log --format="%h %<(10, cut)%ci"
```

and it should output

```
06bcd4c 2016-01-01
11fae28 2015-12-30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to remove the `..` using control characters. E.g.

```
git log --format="%h %<(12,trunc)%ci%x08%x08"
```

which will output something like

```
06bcd4c 2016-01-01
11fae28 2015-12-30
```

The log statement above use `%x08` after the truncated format. `x08` is the backspace control character that removes one output character. So `%x08%x08` will remove `..`.

PS: Since `trunc` only appends `..` if the string gets truncated the solution above only works if it is sure that the string will be truncated. Otherwise it removes the last two characters of the output string and not the `..`.